# How to use HTML Parser to get Facebook source from origin

Tags: html, facebook, parsing, html-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to get the Facebook source code from users on facebook when I manually try going onto a users page it will give me all the data.

This line of code in the html seems to be the difference:

> meta name="referrer" content="origin-when-crossorigin"
>   id="meta_referrer"

When the program gets the html this is what is given:

> meta name="referrer" content="default" id="meta_referrer">

This is the code, I am using Jsoup which is a Java library

```
public void test() throws IOException {     

String html = Jsoup.connect("https://www.facebook.com/*adduseridhere*").get().html(); 

System.out.println(html);   }
```

So my question is, Is there a way my program can function in the same way my browser does when gathering the html data?

Comment: Scraping their HTML source code is against Facebook’s ToS.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send some header data as below.

First look what sends your browser to that link from browser and after try to implement it with jsoup.

As i see in your example you don't send any header data therefore facebook does not accept it from browser

```
Document doc = Jsoup
        .connect(url.trim())
        .timeout(3000)
        .header("Host", "someip")
        .header("Connection", "keep-alive")
        .header("Content-Length", "111")
        .header("Cache-Control", "max-age=0")
        .header("Accept",
                "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8")
        .header("User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36")
        .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        .header("Referer", url.trim())
        .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch")
        .header("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6")
        .userAgent("Mozilla")
        .get();
```